# Processing middleman transactions

Tags: paypal, payment-processing

How do applications like AirBnB handle transactions in terms of taking a commission and paying out a host?

What platform i.e. PayPal would allow for making EFTs to different bank accounts automatically via an API call?

Is this even possible or are these kinds of transactions handled in a more manual way? I would really like some input on this matter.

Answer (score 1):

The most common solution, which I think AirBnB might actually use some flavor of, is to send payments to a PayPal email address [using Payouts](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/integrate/prerequisites/#get-access-to-paypal-payouts) -- and then the recipient gets the money in their PayPal balance and can use or withdraw it to their bank however they want.

Comment: How do you think they might handle the direct deposit method? Or would this be manual?